# django multilinguage website @login_required redirect issue

Tags: python, django, django-multilingual

I'm developing a multilingual website using 
django 1.11 ,

'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' middleware and

i18n_patterns

I use @login_required decorator for my views (for redirecting user to login page when he's not logged in)
but it doesn't redirect user based on current language .
for example when (not logged in) user goes to /fr/user/profile
it will be redirected to /en/accounts/login?next=/fr/user/profile  (but it should redirects to /fr/accounts/login?next=/fr/user/profile ) 
(because default website language is en(english) it always redirects to default language )

Comment: What is your `LOGIN_URL` setting?

Comment: My login url is /accounts/login

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hard-code settings, Django can handle url name like this:

`LOGIN_URL = 'registration:login'`

Checkout this: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L255